# Russian peasant multiplication in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, xilinx-ise

I'm using Xilinx ISE to compile and simulate VHDL code. And I'm trying to compute the multiplication of two 8-bit numbers using the [Russian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication).
The following code is how I'm currently doing it:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity multiplier is
    port (
        multiplier : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
        multiplicand : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
        y : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0)
    );
end multiplier;

architecture Behavioral of multiplier is
begin
    process (multiplier, multiplicand)
        variable a : unsigned(7 downto 0) := unsigned(multiplier);
        variable b : unsigned(15 downto 0) := "00000000" & unsigned(multiplicand);
       variable c : unsigned(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    begin
        while a /= "00000001" loop
            a := a srl 1;
            b := b sll 1;
            if a(0) = '1' then
                c := c + b;
            end if;
        end loop;
        y <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(c);
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

The Check Syntax button works fine but View RTL schematics fails to execute. Also when I try to simulate the code in the ISim software I get `The simulator has terminated in an unexpected manner. Please review the ISim log (isim.log) for details.

I've been trying to debug this code for half a day now and it seems like I'm working with user unfriendliest language on the user unfriendliest software.

Comment: Your variable initial values should be variable assignments in the process sequence of statements. While loops aren't supported in Xilinx's Integrated Synthesis Environment. You should have some synthesis log messages. Issues would schematic simulation would be off topic here. None of this is a VHDL language issue.

Comment: Variables are initialized once during elaboration.   Not every time the process runs.   Hence the statement from @user16145658 that you instead need to do these as variable assignments.

Comment: While loops are not synthesizable.   For loops are.   You could use a for loop with a'range instead.    The hardware you create will need to be independent of the value of multiplier, hence, there is not much value in exiting the loop early (other than to improve simulation performance - but doing this might disturb the hardware you are trying to create).    Once you get the algorithm working, it would be interesting to see if your synthesis tool can then build a balanced tree of adders rather than a non-optimal linear cascade of them.

Comment: Are you aware that VHDL is not a _programming_ language, but a _description_ language? It was designed to describe hardware, and only some extensions target simulation and make it look as a programming language. However, those are not synthesizable.

Comment: @user16145658 Is it possible for you to write a for-loop version that works? I have tried several times, it compiles but yields the wrong results.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] along with a testbench and provide the expected result as well as what you got as a result for the version with the for loop. The ISE pdf will tell you whether it supports the exit statement (and potentially next statement).

Comment: "The simulation has terminated in an unexpected manner" points to an ISIM bug ... possibly (but not definitely) triggered by faulty VHDL.  Different ISIM releases have different bugs; certainly below ISIM 10, you don't say which release you're using. Try a better simulator, at least to get better diagnostics in the case of a bug.

Comment: Your multiply while loop will never finish for a multipler equal to 0.  Using a for loop with a'range for the discrete range of the parameter will have a finite number of iterations and should evaluate a(0) = '1' and assign c := c + b; conditionally before the shifts on a and b. Provide that [mcve] providing a wrong answer.