# Russian peasant multiplication in VHDL always results in zero

Tags: vhdl

I am implementing [Russian peasant algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Russian_peasant_multiplication) in VHDL. I have the following code.

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity russian_peasant is
  port (
    multiplicand : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    multiplier : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    product : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
  );
end entity;

architecture behavioral of russian_peasant is
begin
  process(multiplicand, multiplier)
    variable m : unsigned(7 downto 0) := unsigned(multiplicand);
    variable n : unsigned(7 downto 0) := unsigned(multiplier);
    variable p : unsigned(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');
  begin
    for i in 0 to 7 loop
      if m(i) = '1' then
        p := p + (n * 2**i);
      end if;
    end loop;
    product <= std_logic_vector(p);
  end process;
end architecture;
```

It compiles fine, but when I simulate it, why does it always yield zero as the result?

[image]

Comment: This isn't [Russian Peasant Multiplication](https://mathcurious.com/2019/12/29/the-russian-multiplication-method/)  using halving and doubling of the multiplier and multiplicand. Your code itself relying on two multiplications per bit (`n * 2**i`)  in binary long multiplication. Provide a [mcve]. Your [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76336894/russian-peasant-multiplication-in-vhdl) has a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/134612400) addressing the same issue wherein you also mistakenly shifted ***before*** conditionally adding b to c based on a being odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your process has `m`, `n` and `p` variables that are initialized only in the process declarative part. These assignment are evaluated only once during elaboration (think at startup of simulation). They are not evaluated each time the process gets executed.

You should probably rewrite the process with assignments as the first statements like:

```
  process(multiplicand, multiplier)
    variable m : unsigned(7 downto 0);
    variable n : unsigned(7 downto 0);
    variable p : unsigned(15 downto 0);
  begin
    m := unsigned(multiplicand);
    n := unsigned(multiplier);
    p := (others => '0');
    for i in 0 to 7 loop
      -- ...
```